# R: can't add row to a dataframe from within a function

Tags: r

I have a function where I want it to add its result to a dataframe. However, this doesn't seem to work. If I try the following:

```
testdf <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 0))
testfunction <- function() {
     testdf[nrow(testdf) + 1,] <- list("a")
}
testfunction()
testdf

[1] matrix.ncol...1..nrow...0.
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

It doesn't add a row. But if I do what's in the `testfunction()` directly, it works:

```
testdf[nrow(testdf) + 1,] <- list("a")
testdf

matrix.ncol...1..nrow...0.
1                          a
```

Why is this the case and how can I add a row of data to a dataframe from within a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the best way to do this would be to pass your data frame to the function as a parameter, and then to return the modified data frame to the caller.

```
testfunction <- function(df) {
    df[nrow(df) + 1,] <- list("a")
    return(df)
}

testdf <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 0))
testdf <- testfunction(testdf)
testdf
```

You *could* also keep everything the same but use the global assignment operator `<<-`:

```
testfunction <- function() {
    testdf[nrow(testdf) + 1,] <<- list("a")    # generally bad
}
```

But there are potential caveats with doing this, and the first option I gave is preferable.